# Should the Appcelerator and Titanium tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

On StackOverflow there are 2 tags, [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator) and [titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/titanium). Both are more or less the same and are about the same platform.

In my opinion the Titanium tag should be a synonym of Appcelerator. The [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator) tag is also the one being monitored by the community.

Comment: Well, the tag-excerpt for [appcelerator] seems to disagree.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. Helps people to find an answer quicker and don't need to use both tags if they aren't sure which one is right

Comment: We also need to consider [appcelerator-titanium].

Comment: @Deduplicator yes... though that can easily be changed. Also great for preventing duplicate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I tested tags and see that there is a tag [appcelerator-titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator-titanium) that appears in case you type appcelerator or type titanium. The logic dictates to me to use always the combined tag.

We must educate people to use the combined tag and in the future will be no doubt about what we are talking. Titanium is a subset of Appcelerator, that can work alone obviously, but it is a core part so naming Appcelerator in the tag doesn't hurt.